# django update statement not updating database as expected

Tags: python, django, orm

I have django framework code where I am updating my database with simple found or not found on a condition where if cdr_number is equel to aparty variable update the database found if not update it with not found. but somehow even cdr_number is equal to aparty variable my code is still not updating the database with found although my if condition is working properly all the print statements and other operations are working. I have shared my print statements also for reference. please someone help on this thanks.

```
            for index,cdr_number in enumerate(cdr_numbers):
                # Read the CSV file
                # tests = reqData.objects.filter(data_id = data_ids[index])
                test = temp_cdr_number[index].rec_data                

                if str(aparty) ==  cdr_number:
                    print(f"{aparty} FOUND")
                    # print(f"{temp_cdr_number[index].data_id} {temp_cdr_number[index].req_data}")
                    # COPY CDR TO CDRS FOLDER
                    os.system(f"cp {file_path}{xlsx_file} cdrs/92{xlsx_file[:10]}-{data_ids[index]}.xlsx")
                    # UPDATE DATA IN REQ_DATA TABLE
                    # reqData.objects.filter(data_id=data_ids[index]).update(rec_data=f"{test}-{index}")
                    
                    print(reqData.objects.filter(data_id=data_ids[index]).update(rec_data=f"Found").query)
                    # print(f"found updated {result}")
                    # print(f"data_id : {data_ids[index]}")
                    # RENAME FILE TO GLOBAL CSV
                    os.rename(f'{file_path}{xlsx_file}',f"{file_path}global_csv.csv")

                    # SAVE CDR INTO DATABASE
                    # os.system("mysql -u root -p12341234 --execute='TRUNCATE ACCESS.global_csv;'")                        
                    # os.system("mysql -u root -p12341234 --execute='SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;'")
                    # os.system(f"mysqlimport -u root -p12341234 --local --fields-terminated-by=',' ACCESS {file_path}global_csv.csv")
                    # os.system(f"mysql -u root -p12341234 --execute='CALL `ACCESS`.`ufone_imei_response`({req_id});'") # MOB IMEI RESPONSE MYSQL STORE PROCEDURE                    
                    break
                else:
                    print(f"not found {aparty}")
                    # print(f"{cdr_number} not found in ufone attachment {aparty}")
                    print(reqData.objects.filter(data_id=data_ids[index]).update(rec_data="Not Found").query)
                    # print(f"not found updated {result}")
                    # reqData.objects.filter(data_id=data_ids[index]).update(rec_data=f"{test}-{index}")
```

**output of print statements**

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
not found 923137925707
not found updated 1
923137925707 FOUND
found updated 1
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
not found 923153174508
not found updated 1
not found 923153174508
not found updated 1
923153174508 FOUND
found updated 1
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
not found 923333152031
not found updated 1
not found 923333152031
not found updated 1
not found 923333152031
not found updated 1
923333152031 FOUND
found updated 1
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
923195823315 FOUND
found updated 1
```

Comment: maybe you should use `.save()` and later `.query`

Answer (score 0):

Documentation: [Updating multiple objects at once](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)

```
Be aware that the update() method is converted directly to an SQL statement. 
It is a bulk operation for direct updates. It doesn’t run any save() methods 
on your models, or emit the pre_save or post_save signals (which are 
a consequence of calling save()), or honor the auto_now field option. 
If you want to save every item in a QuerySet and make sure that the save() 
method is called on each instance, you don’t need any special function to handle that. 
Loop over them and call save():

for item in my_queryset:
    item.save()
```

So you may need

```
my_queryset = reqData.objects.filter(data_id=data_ids[index]).update(rec_data=f"Found")

print(my_queryset.query)

for item in my_queryset:
    item.save()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'save'. this error is raised when using save. and I noticed my_queryset will return only number of rows it has updated. So print(my_queryset.query) gives the same error object has no attribute 'save'.

Comment: it is strange that it worked when you was using directly `.query` in `reqData.objects.filter(data_id=data_ids[index]).update(rec_data=f"Found").query` because it should give the same error.

Comment: it gives same error on .query. even .query is not working

Comment: without working code which I could run I have no idea what can makes problem.  So I can't help more.